# OpenGL shader hot reload (multiple contexts?)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, opengl

I wrote a simple directory monitor using `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` (WinApi). It asynchronously reads file/directory changes (in a background thread) and invokes a callback once a change was monitored.

```
m_ResourceMonitor.SetNotification(m_ResourcePath, [&](const std::wstring& file)
            {
                auto& shader = ... //Load shader from cache
                shader->Reload(buff);
                shader->Compile();
            });
```

`Reload(sourceBuffer)` calls `glShaderSource()`. This call, however, fails since no OpenGL context is running on the monitor thread. My design options:

- Create an event queue (i.e. using `PostMessage()`) and "subscribe" to the directory change event
- Something like: `MainThread.Invoke(func)`. Similar to #1, but allows executing a function (in this case `Reload()`) on main thread
- Creating **a second OpenGL context** just for reloading shaders/maybe textures. Sharing all resources across contexts

What is considered best practice? I don't want to introduce too much concurrency overhead for this feature. A second context is atm my favorite option, as it enables async texture loading/streaming in the future.

Also I am not sure if `glShaderSource()` is all you have to do in order to reload your shader. Many implementations call `glDeleteProgram(()` first and then `glLinkProgram()` the shader program again. Is deleting the program really the only option? Thanks!

Comment: How are you going to deal with the potentially changing uniform (or maybe even attribute) locations after a relink, and the loss of the uniform values at relink? I think you won't get around of telling you render threads about the relink anyway,

Comment: I am using GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER. So the uniform data should be in a separate buffer. Also I use glGetUniformLocation to adress uniforms by name instead of index.

Comment: This might work as long as you don't use `sampler` uniforms...

Comment: in this case I would need to uniform my textures again after link(). Thats why I am asking. Is deleting the program really needed?

Comment: You don't need to delete the program. you can re-link an existing program object. But the uniforms are lost in any case.